# How do I pass data from the views.py backend to html template frontend in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am very new to coding and Django and have read the documentations but couldn't seem to figure out the answer, your guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I have variables in my Django views.py file and want to pass it into my template file so it can be displayed in html. How do I do that?

For example, in views.py

```
    list = [2, 5, 10, "string", 99, ]
```

And I wish to this use list in my frontend HTML or javascript

Comment: Can't find the doc ? It's here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 0):

Usings views you can send your data from your server (django) to your frontend (html)

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from polls.models import Poll
import datetime

def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': p})
```

In html

```
{% poll %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/views/

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty broad and there's a lot of good tutorials out there (including from the Django project itself), but I'll try to help you.

Let's say you want to display each element of your list `elementList = [2,5,10,"string,99]` as a list item in your template. You could iterate over it in the template with something like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for element in elementList %}
        <li>{{ element }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Check out [the tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/) for more details.